# How to adjust the index of an array passed as a parameter?

Tags: autohotkey

I have rewritten the _Array base object to allow for 0 base arrays but I noticed a bug of sorts that I would appreciate some help with.

The relevant adjustments:

```
Array(_parameters*) {
    r := {}

    Loop, % Round(_parameters.Length())
        r[A_Index - 1] := _parameters[A_Index]

    r.base := _Array

    Return (r)
}

Class _Array {
    Length[] {
        Get {
            Return (Round(this.MaxIndex() + 1))
        }
    }

    IsArray[] {
        Get {
            Return (1)
        }
    }
    Push(_elements*) {
        s := this.Length, m := Round(_elements.MaxIndex())

        If (m)
            this.InsertAt(s, _elements*)

        Return (s + m)
    }

    Concat(_elements*) {
        r := this.Clone()

        MsgBox, % "222: " . _elements.Length() ;_elements.Length is not acceptable because this special parameter array (A_Args) does not get modified.
        MsgBox, % "333: " . (_elements.base.__Class ? "y" : "n")    ;No base.

        For i, v in _elements {
            If (v.IsArray) {
                Loop, % v.Length
                    r.Push(v[A_Index - 1])
            }

            Else
                r.Push(v)   ;Catch for objects and string/integer values.
        }

        Return (r)
    }
    Join(_separator := ",") {
        s := Round(this.MaxIndex())

        For i, v in this
            r .= (v.IsArray ? "[Array]" : IsObject(v) ? "{Object}" : v) . (i < s ? _separator : "")

        Return (r)
    }
}
```

The issue:

```
F1::
    arrays := [[1,2,3]
        , [4,5,6]
        , [7,8,9]]

    MsgBox, % "111: " . arrays.Length

    MsgBox, % [].concat(arrays*).Join(", ") ;[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. Missing [1, 2, 3]

    Return
```

I have confirmed that passing arrays* as a parameter creates an A_Args array but it has no base to manipulate. Is there anything I can do to fix this behaviour?